# Spark AR | how to freeze and stop camera scene while recording

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I'm creating a instagram filter which requires the scene to stop or the frame to freeze for a few seconds while recording. Is there any way I can do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet. But seems like a relatively popular question/request on the SparkAR Facebook community. When it becomes available, it'll be big news.

https://www.facebook.com/groups/SparkARcommunity/permalink/605773363168043/

https://www.facebook.com/groups/SparkARcommunity/permalink/583833255362054/

https://www.facebook.com/groups/SparkARcommunity/permalink/760366351042076/

https://www.reddit.com/r/SparkArStudio/comments/d50xd5/delay_on_camera_texture/